# How to return a dictionary based on a certain element in the list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a list of lists that contains a tuple and an integer, how to return a dictionary based on a certain element in the list?

```py
[[('A Sam', 'count1'), 1],
 [('A Sam', 'count2'), 2],
 [('T King', 'count1'), 2],
 [('C Baskin', 'count2'), 1]]
```

Given this, as input, I need to return a dictionary

```py
{"A Sam": [1,2], "T King": [2,0], "C Baskin": [0,1]}
```

as the output.
For a particular key named "A Sam" the value of the dictionary should be a list of count1 and count2 where count1 and count2 are the 2 elements in the list of lists. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: please share what you have tried so far

Comment: What are the `0` in the result `{"A Sam": [1,2], "T King": [2,0], "C Baskin": [0,1]}`? Why isn't the result `{"A Sam": [1,2], "T King": [2], "C Baskin": [1]}`?

Comment: @Grismar the output is required to be like that.

Comment: @Grismar The OP wants to have counts of `'count1'` and `'count2'`, if you don't have for example `'count1'` for some element you get 0 and vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

It is little bit long but it works.

```py
l=[[('A Sam', 'count1'), 1], [('A Sam', 'count2'), 2], [('T King', 'count1'), 2], [('C Baskin', 'count2'), 1]]
D={}
for j in l:
    if j[0][0] in D:
        if j[0][1]=='count1':
            D[j[0][0]][0]=j[1]
        else:
            D[j[0][0]][1]=j[1]
    else:
        if j[0][1]=='count1':
            D[j[0][0]]=[j[1],0]
        else:
            D[j[0][0]]=[0,j[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(lambda :[0] * 2) # defaultdict that returns [0, 0]

for (name, count), n in lst:
  v = dct[name]
  v[int(count[-1]) - 1] += n # get the last element from 'count' and use it as index
```

Output:

```
{'A Sam': [1, 2], 'C Baskin': [0, 1], 'T King': [2, 0]})
```